# Get names data in alphabetical order with section headings in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below, was trying to get the data in JSON format 2D array but no success. I've tried different methods, but unable to achieve it. Please guide me to get the result.

***Forgot to upload the code, here is the updated question with my trial code.

```
id   company_name 
-----------------
1    Alexa          
2    Cisco          
3    Blackberry     
4    Amazon         
5    Deka           
6    Colgate        
7    Dell           
8    BBC
```

I want to get that data like below in 2D `JSON` format array.

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      heading: 'A',
      data: [
        {id: 4, text: 'Amazon'},
        {id: 1, text: 'Alexa'},
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      heading: 'B',
      data: [
        {id: 8, text: 'BBC'},
        {id: 3, text: 'Blackberry'},
      ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        heading: 'C',
        data: [
          {id: 2, text: 'Cisco'},
          {id: 6, text: 'Colgate'},
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        heading: 'D',
        data: [
          {id: 5, text: 'Deka'},
          {id: 7, text: 'Dell'},
        ]
    }
]
```

I am trying with the below code, but not yet succeed. I am still trying, if anyone come up with a help, would be very much appreciated.

```
$query = mysqli_query($dblink,"SELECT id,company_name FROM company_names ORDER BY company_name");

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $id = $row["id"];
  $letter = strtolower(substr($row["company_name"],0,1));
  if(is_numeric($letter)) $letter = "0-9";
  if(!isset($data[$letter])){
  $data[$letter] = array();}
  $data[$letter][] = $row["company_name"];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: To be able to guide you I need to know what code do you already have? Not to start with booting your computer and installing web server... i.e. upload the php code you have developed yet.

Comment: where are your trials? you can't just simply select the rows and expect them to build the json structure themselves you know, and why in the world is this question being upvoted

Comment: @Ghost  Sorry, i forgot to add the code, update the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, I added to your code only setting additional columns to the result array.

```
$data = array();
$id = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $letter = strtoupper($row["company_name"]{0});
  if(is_numeric($letter)) $letter = "0-9";
  if(!isset($data[$letter])) {
     $data[$letter]['heading'] = $letter;
     $data[$letter]['id'] = $id++;
  }
  $data[$letter]['data'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/913142)

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost got it, but how can avoid letters(A:,B:,C:...) at start i.e., i need a 2D array instead of 3D array. Eg: 
[{"heading": "A", "id": 1, "data": [{"id": 1, "company_name": "Alexa"},{"id": 4,"company_name": "Amazon"}]},{"heading": "B", "id": 1, "data": [{"id": 8, "company_name": "BBC"},{"id": 3,"company_name": "Blackberry"}]}]